# Looping through database with array and save data into variable Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have an array which stores vehicles models. And i have a database table with all vehicles compatibility.

I need to through database table and find all vehicles that in array.
Actually I did it and I can loop through the database with array and get all necessary information about vehicles. But my problem is I cannot save the data to the variable. For some reason it's empty.

But if i just want to display data with echo function I can actually do this.

Here is my code:

```
$listing = str_replace( ", ", ",", $model );
        
        $modle_arrs = explode(',', $listing);

        foreach($modle_arrs as $modle_arr){
            
            $e_compts = EbayCompatrbilityCategorie::all()->where('model', $modle_arr);
            
            $compt_val = "{";
                foreach ($e_compts as $e_compt) {
                    $compt_val .= "[" . $e_compt['year'] . "]";
                    $compt_val .= "[" . $e_compt['model'] . "]";
                    
                    echo "[" . $e_compt['year'] . "]";
                    echo "[" . $e_compt['model'] . "]";
                }
            $compt_val .= "}";

        }

        dd($compt_val);
```

And here is output in browser:
[image]

How can I store data into variable in this situation?

Comment: What format is `$compt_val` supposed to be in?

Comment: It should be string.

Comment: Is it possible in the last iteration the query comes back empty? You're overwriting $compt_val on every iteration, so if the last query is empty, you'll get an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `$compt_val` on every iteration. If the query comes back as empty on the last iteration, `$compt_val` will be empty. Try keeping all the values in an array:

```
$listing = str_replace( ", ", ",", $model );

$modle_arrs = explode(',', $listing);
$compt_val_all = [];
foreach($modle_arrs as $modle_arr){

    $e_compts = EbayCompatrbilityCategorie::all()->where('model', $modle_arr);

    $compt_val = "{";
        foreach ($e_compts as $e_compt) {
            $compt_val .= "[" . $e_compt['year'] . "]";
            $compt_val .= "[" . $e_compt['model'] . "]";

            echo "[" . $e_compt['year'] . "]";
            echo "[" . $e_compt['model'] . "]";
        }
    $compt_val .= "}";
    $compt_val_all[] = $compt_val;
}

dd($compt_val_all);
```

Comment: Great! Keep an eye out for those variable-initialization-inside-foreachs, they're easy to miss! Good luck.

Comment: One more time thanks you. Yes, I totally forgot about overwriting.